# Handling Nuget package errors on a small .NET development team using VSTS

Tags: .net, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

**Background of issue**: I’ve been having issues with getting my new team members projects setup correctly with our .NET projects using VSTS. The issues regard Nuget packages. Lots of warnings on the references in each project in our solution.

- Nuget restore doesn’t work correctly
- ‘update-package –reinstall’ worked once but can’t be replicated.
- I’ve added a .tfignore to the solution but the Nuget references have been baked into these projects for years. Their claws are in so many files that version control is still having issues.
- I’ve gotten the solution and projects up and running on 2 machines but it takes a lot of time and is hard to replicate.

**Question**: How would you handle this issue in a small team of 4 people? I’m thinking of doing one or both of the following.

*Create new projects*

1. Create the project
2. Add .tfignore
3. Move over code
4. Add references back in and ensure they’re not being ignored and
   not being uploaded to tfs

*Create build server in VSTS*

1. Use build server as the controlled space and replicate it’s environment on team members machines. I think this is one of its purposes. I know the least about this and am still gathering details.

There might be a tool I’ve missed that I should be using. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I use a local nuget server across a number of developers, so simply stating "Nuget restore doesn’t work correctly" doesn't fly, as you can get it working.  Perhaps you could share what errors you are getting?

Comment: We're not using a local nuget server for our developers. I'll look into it.

Comment: Why are "the paths baked into these projects" not working? does every user get a different path for their `packages` directory?

Comment: Great question. I have a web API, console app, and MVC app in my solution. Although I've added the .tfignore to the solution and projects, some packages are still tracked in a projects web.config, .csproj, .nuget, or packages.config. I assume this, perhaps incorrectly, is causing the NuGet Package Manager to think these packages are still installed even after I've removed them.

Previously I hoped to find a fix for my issue- believing I was a Package Manager Console command away from a fix.I believe now the problem is my approach to managing these packages for my team. That's the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s  unnecessary to add packages in source control. And you can use one `.tfignore` in the root of your TFVC repo to exclude all the packages across different solutions.

You can follow below steps:

1. Create your projects and `.tfignore`

   Create `.tfignore` file in the root of your TFVC repo, and add below contents to ignore packages, build artifacts file etc:

   ```
   **\*.suo
   **\*.user

   # Build results
   **\bin
   **\obj

   #include nuget executable
   !**\NuGet.exe

   #nuget packages directory
   **\packages

   #include package target files which may be required for msbuild
   !**\packages/*.targets

   # Publish Web Output
   **\*.Publish.xml
   **\*.pubxml

   **\.vs
   ```
2. Add the projects and .tfignore into source control

   In Source Control Explorer, click `Add Items to folder`, select the `.tfignore` and the projects.

   [image]

   Then make sure the `packages` folder for each project is not added.

   [image]

   If the `packages` folder is added, then use **undo pending changes** to remove the packages folder in source control.

   [image]
3. Checkin changes

   In Pending changes, checkin the changes.

Besides, except the way above, you can also refer the post [How to keep packages folder out of TFVC](http://donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-keep-packages-folder-out-of-TFVC) by Donovan Brown.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to make sure that I was approaching this problem correctly and your answer helped me in doing so. I appreciate it :)